# If RegularExpression Validator catches an error do x in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am quite new to ASP.Net and so am quite unsure of a lot of things and learning as I go. In one of the forms I have made I have validated the fields, and if the data is not of the correct format I throw an error as below.

[image]

If the data is ok then it shows the graph as below.

[image]

The problem I am having is if the user then changes the fields and they throw and error I can't seem to remove the table, and so the error appears below the table.

[image]

I can't put table.visible = false in the method that creates the table as I am assuming the error from the validator prevents that method from running. For the same reasons I can't seem to put it in the is postback method either. I am wondering if there is a way to do this where I can check whether the validator has caught an error and turn the table visiblity to false?

So theoretically:

if (validatorCaughtError == true)
{
        table.visiblity = false;
}

Comment: is this webforms (.aspx) or mvc (cshtml)?

Comment: webforms....will edit this thanks.

Comment: 1) Create a variable at the page to hold the table visibility. 2) If an exception happens when validating, set the variable to false. 3) Override the PreRender event to set the table visibility based on the variable.

Comment: Post the ASPX and the C# code to see how are you doing the things